# pandas dataframe index match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do an "index & match" type function that is popular in excel.  For example - given two pandas DataFrames, update the df_1 with information found in df_2:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'num_a':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                     'num_b':[2, 4, 1, 2, 3]})    
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'num':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                     'name':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
```

I'm working with data sets that have ~80,000 rows in both df_1 and df_2 and my goal is to create two new columns in df_1, "name_a" and "name_b".

Below is the most efficient method that I could come up with. There *has* to be a better way!

```
name_a = []
name_b = []
for i in range(len(df_1)):

    name_a.append(df_2.name.iloc[df_2[
                  df_2.num == df_1.num_a.iloc[i]].index[0]])
    name_b.append(df_2.name.iloc[df_2[
                  df_2.num == df_1.num_b.iloc[i]].index[0]])

df_1['name_a'] = name_a
df_1['name_b'] = name_b
```

Resulting in:

```
>>> df_1.head()
   num_a  num_b name_a name_b
0      1      2      a      b
1      2      4      b      d
2      3      1      c      a
3      4      2      d      b
4      5      3      e      c
```

Answer (score 5):

**High Level**

- Create a dictionary to use in a `replace`
- `replace`, `rename` columns, and `join`

---

```
m = dict(zip(
    df_2.num.values.tolist(),
    df_2.name.values.tolist()
))

df_1.join(
    df_1.replace(m).rename(
        columns=lambda x: x.replace('num', 'name')
    )
)

   num_a  num_b name_a name_b
0      1      2      a      b
1      2      4      b      d
2      3      1      c      a
3      4      2      d      b
4      5      3      5      c
```

---

**Breakdown**

`replace` with a dictionary should be pretty quick.  There are bunch of ways to build a dictionary form `df_2`.  As a matter of fact we could have used a `pd.Series`.  I chose to build with `dict` and `zip` because I find that it's faster.

**Building `m`**

*Option 1*

```
m = df_2.set_index('num').name
```

*Option 2*

```
m = df_2.set_index('num').name.to_dict()
```

*Option 3*

```
m = dict(zip(df_2.num, df_2.name))
```

*Option 4 (My Choice)*

```
m = dict(zip(df_2.num.values.tolist(), df_2.name.values.tolist()))
```

*`m` build times*

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 325 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 376 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.9 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.4 µs per loop

%timeit df_2.set_index('num').name
%timeit df_2.set_index('num').name.to_dict()
%timeit dict(zip(df_2.num, df_2.name))
%timeit dict(zip(df_2.num.values.tolist(), df_2.name.values.tolist()))
```

---

**Replacing `num`**

Again, we have choices, here are a few and their times.

```
%timeit df_1.replace(m)
%timeit df_1.applymap(lambda x: m.get(x, x))
%timeit df_1.stack().map(lambda x: m.get(x, x)).unstack()

1000 loops, best of 3: 792 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 959 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 925 µs per loop
```

I choose...

```
df_1.replace(m)

  num_a num_b
0     a     b
1     b     d
2     c     a
3     d     b
4     5     c
```

**Rename columns**

```
df_1.replace(m).rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('num', 'name'))

  name_a name_b   <-- note the column name change
0      a      b
1      b      d
2      c      a
3      d      b
4      5      c
```

**Join**

```
df_1.join(df_1.replace(m).rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('num', 'name')))

   num_a  num_b name_a name_b
0      1      2      a      b
1      2      4      b      d
2      3      1      c      a
3      4      2      d      b
4      5      3      5      c
```

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a more straightforward solution than those already offered. Since you mentioned Excel, this is a basic vlookup. You can simulate this in pandas by using [Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html).

```
name_map = dict(df_2.set_index('num').name)

df_1['name_a'] = df_1.num_a.map(name_map)
df_1['name_b'] = df_1.num_b.map(name_map)

df_1

   num_a  num_b name_a name_b
0      1      2      a      b
1      2      4      b      d
2      3      1      c      a
3      4      2      d      b
4      5      3      e      c
```

All we do is convert df_2 to a dict with 'num' as the keys. The map function looks up each value from a df_1 column in the dict and returns the corresponding letter. No complicated indexing required.

Answer (score 0):

Just try a conditional statement:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'num_a':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                     'num_b':[2, 4, 1, 2, 3]})    
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'num':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                     'name':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
df_1["name_a"] = df_2["num_b"]
df_1["name_b"] = np.array(df_1["name_a"][df_1["num_b"]-1]) 
print(df_1)

   num_a  num_b name_a name_b
0      1      2      a      b
1      2      4      b      d
2      3      1      c      a
3      4      2      d      b
4      5      3      e      c
```